# Form is blank when opened by program but not in Designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make an information tracker where the user inputs their data and the inputs are saved and recorded. In Visual Studio forms I have created two separate forms that link to each other. The first is where the user will enter their username and password and clicking enter should bring them to the next page where they would add their information for that day. The first form displays correctly when I run the program but when I try to bring up the next form it is completely grey and none of the elements I put on in Designer are there. The screenshots are of how the second form looks in Designer vs how it looks when I run the program.

[image: Image in Designer]

[image: Image when opened with the program]

Here's my code for both forms as well:

Form1 (LoginUI):

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoginUI
{
    public partial class StudentInfo : Form
    {
        public StudentInfo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StudentID_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Your code for StudentID_MaskInputRejected
        }

        private void StudentPass_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Your code for StudentPass_MaskInputRejected
        }

        private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create an instance of the CodeUI form and show it
            CodeUI form2 = new CodeUI();
            form2.ShowDialog();

           // Close the old form
           // this.Close();
        }
    }

    // Define the CodeUI class outside the event handler
    public class CodeUI : Form
    {
        public CodeUI()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Form2 (CodeUI):

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CodeUI
{
    public partial class CodeUI : Form
    {
        public CodeUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += CodeUILoadHandler; // Rename the event handler
        }

        private void CodeUILoadHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Your custom initialization code for CodeUI
        }

        private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle the button click event
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried every solution I can think of and brought it to one of my coding teachers for help but they didn't know either. I'm not very well versed in coding so any help or advice you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have a duplicate empty declaration of `CodeUI` in `StudentsForm` than that's your culprit.

I mean that part:

```cs
// Define the CodeUI class outside the event handler
public class CodeUI : Form
{
    public CodeUI()
    {     
    }
}
```

It does nothing except "hiding" real implemented `CodeUI` form. So just remove it.